# Bootstrap Issue with Rounded Border around Columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've never been more livid in my life after spending close to three hours simply trying to format three columns. I'm just starting using html and I have no clue why I'm having so much trouble with columns. I can't seem to ever get them where I want them to be. I simply am trying to have 3 columns with some text in them that each have a border with rounded edges around them. They should all be the same size, text margine centered etc. And then I planned to have them like change color when scrolled over, though I can't even do the first part.

I found this: http://jsfiddle.net/6nVdT/

`THE CODE SHOULD BE LINKED IT'S KIND OF LONG`

which is kind of similar to what I want, and even when I copy paste it it is different. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I copy paste that and just like in all my attempts the text is terribly uncentered, the boxes are all different sizes, they don't take up the whole area. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the CSS.

To get the example working put the CSS in a style tag in the HTML file.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

```
<style>
    /*CSS goes here*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a new html file, maybe you didn't place the css properly or your existing css is affecting it.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.col-w {
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 8px solid #B2A68E;
        padding: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
        width:28%;
    }
    div.col-w div.col-w {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top:-18px;
        margin-bottom:-18px;
    }
    div.col-w2 {
        left:100%;
        margin-left:23px;
    }
    div.col-w3 {
        left:100%;
        margin-left:23px;
    }

    div.col-w.col-b {
        font-size: 0;
        height: 8px;
    }

    div.col-w div.col-h {
        position:relative;
        float: left;
        width:100%;
        margin-right: -100%;
    }
    div.col-1 {
        left:-200%;
        margin-left:-83px;
    }
    div.col-2 {
        left:-100%;
        margin-left:-43px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body> 
    <div class="col-w">
        <div class="col-w col-w2">
            <div class="col-w col-w3">
                  <div class="col-h col-1">
                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p>Founded in 1995 in Atlanta, Georgia, The Creative Circus is an accredited, two-year, portfolio-building, educational program for the creative side of the Advertising, Interactive Development, Design and Photography industries. Located in an energetic, converted warehouse that feels more like an agency, design firm or studio than a traditional school, future creatives build portfolios that help them land the best jobs in the field.</p>
                    <p><a href="http://www.creativecircus.edu">Find out more about us.</a></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-h col-2">
                    <h2>Admissions</h2>

                    <p>The Creative Circus is committed to seeking out and enrolling applicants of high standard. Our school follows a selective admissions process which includes a required admissions interview and portfolio submission. Admission is based on your commitment and dedication to your field of interest as determined by an admissions interview. This selection process allows us to provide a unique creative learning environment filled with the “best-prepared, most avidly sought-after creatives in the industry.”</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-h col-3">
                    <h2>Programs of Study</h2>
                    <p>Since 1995, we’ve seen a lot of changes.  But through all the trends, we still have one mantra – concept is king. Whether you come for Art Direction, Copywriting, Design, Image or Interactive Development, original ideas are what get you hired.</p>
                    <p>For more information about what we teach and why, please <a href="http://www.creativecircus.edu">download our Course Catalog</a></p>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```